# What is an IDL?

Tags: anchor, idl

When talking about Solana programs, I often run across the word "IDL". What is it and what is it used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question to help others:

IDL stands for Interface Definition Language. They are a way for a Solana Program to define it's public interfaces i.e. it's instructions, account formats, and errors in an easy to read JSON format. They were introduced through the popular Anchor framework, which automatically generates these for your programs if written using it.

They are useful for two mains reasons:

- They make interactions far more human readable: Transactions and accounts are just a bunch of bytes concatenated together, so without an IDL we as an outside observer can't really know what the data in a given account or instruction actually represents. Using IDLs, we can easily parse an instruction or account to make sense of what it's actually doing (this is how block explorers are able to nicely display data for some programs).
- They make building client side code far easier: Even if we know what data a program wants, doing the same steps of generating said data and accounts by hand is tedious and error prone. Since IDLs provide a standard interface, a number of tools (most notably Anchor itself) can take advantage of this and make generating instructions to interact with a program far easier.

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree with the above answer. For someone coming from `evm/ethereum` ecosystem, `IDL`s are basically like `ABI / Application Binary Interface` for a smart contract.

Generally solana programs / contracts in evm do not have an interface thats easy to understand. An IDL gives a general overview of what functions are present and what type of parameters can be passed to those functions in program. This makes code and instructions far more easier to understand.